# How to get pop up message texts while automating Mobile App using Appium selenium C#?

Tags: c#, selenium, appium, appium-android

After submitting timesheet form, there is Successful message along with ID and other texts on lighbox kind of popup in mobile app.

I want to select those text and want to save in variable for reporting purpose,   How can I do it Using Appium Selenium in Visual studio C#?

Comment: it would be of help if you could proved a minimal reproducible example. Also consider reading the How to Ask page, to increases chance getting a useful answer. Currently it is not clear what seems to be issue so you should also provide some error or clarify what the problem appears to be

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using appium server with webdriver.io, you would want to use the getText() function and save the results into a variable.

Check out the documentation on the getText Function here: https://webdriver.io/docs/api/element/getText.html

Here is an example:

```
const elem = $('#elem'); //this is the element you want to get text from
const textVariable = elem.getText()
```

`textVariable` will be a string containing the text for element with ID `elem`